# how to handle in nodejs an xlsx file sent in a post request

Tags: node.js, excel, parsing, multipartform-data, xlsx

currently im trying to retrieve a xlsx from a multipart/form-data http request in nodejs;
after parsing the data chunks i managed to get an string that looks like this:

'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\b\x00\x00\x00!\x00b�h^\x01\x00\x00�\x04\x00\x00\x13\x00\b\x02[Content_Types].xml x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00���N�0\x10E�H�C�-Jܲ@\b5��\x12*Q>�ēƪc[�ii����\x10B�\x15j7�\x12��{2��h�nm���ƻR\f����U^\x1B7/���%�\x17\x19�rZY�\x14\x1B@1\x19__�f�\x00�q��R4D�AJ�\x1Ah\x15\x16>����V\x11�ƹ\f�Z�9����NV�\x118ʩ�\x10��\x13�ji){^��-I\x04�"{�\x16v^�P!XS)bR�r��K�s(�3�`c\x02�0���\x0E���\x06��7\x1EM4\x1A�����ZƐk+�|\|z�(���P��6\x15h_-[�@�!���\x00Pk��\x16�2n�}�?\x15�L��� ��%�\x13\x1C��\x1Bd����dN\x18"m,�ǞDO97*�~��ɸ8�O�c\x1C|n��\x07�\x04E��\x14�\x11���B\x10��!$}�����;{���[����\x7F2�\x06\x00\x00��\x03\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\b\x00\x00\x00!\x00�U0#�\x00\x00\x00L\x02\x00\x00\x0B\x00\b\x02_rels/.rels �\x04\x02(�\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00��MO�0\f��H�����ݐ\x10BKwAH�!T~�I�\x0F���$\x1Bݿ'\x1C\x10T\x1A�\x03G\x7F�~����<���!��4��\x12\x14;#�w����qu\x07*&r�Fq���\x11v�����GJy(v��*����K��#F��D�\x10�.W\x1A\t\x13�\x1C�\x16=��Z�MY�b��\x01�BS�����7��ϛ\x7Fז��?�9L�ҙ\x15�sbgٮ|�l!��\x1AUSh9i�b�r:"y_dl��D��\x13�|-N��R"4\x12�2�G�%��\x7FZ�4�˝y�7\të��ɂ�\x1F��\x01\x00\x00��\x03\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\b\x00\x00

the output file from fs.writeFile("filename.xlsx", string, {encoding:"binary"}) is corrupted and i cant open it;
Is there a way to write an xlsx file from that string correctly like the third party library multer does?

im trying to write an xlsx file after parsing the multipart/form-data http request in nodejs
the code i used looks like this:

```
function parseRequest(data, boundary) {
  const bodyString = Buffer.concat(data).toString(); // []
  console.log({ bodyString });
  const bodyParts = bodyString.split(boundary);
  console.log({ bodyParts });
  const body = {};
  const files = [];
  bodyParts.forEach(row => {
    const cleanedRow = row.replace('Content-Disposition: form-data; ', '').split(/[\r\n]+/); //
    if (isFile(cleanedRow)) {
      const { field, file, originalName, mimeType } = returnFileEntry(cleanedRow);
      files.push({ field, file, originalName, mimeType });
    }
    if (isProperty(cleanedRow)) {
      const [field, value] = returnPropertyEntry(cleanedRow);
      body[field] = value;
    }
  });
  return { body, files };
}
```